# Insert Records Into Custom Table via Rest API

Tags: rest, acumatica

I have add a new custom Table into the database. Then added it to a Customization Project so that Acumatica will see it.  I am trying to Extended the Web Service API to add new call so that I can do an insert into this Table via Rest API.  When I try to extended it I don't see an option to Insert as an action like I do when looking at some existing screens.  Is this even possible and if there any documentation on extending to do this?

Comment: Did you add your custom table to the graph you are extending via a View? Then you should be able to extend the endpoint

Comment: I only did a DAC for it. It isn’t part of a screen or extension to an existing functionality.   Looking to just get the data in and then use in as additional info for a generic inquiry.

Comment: You would need a graph that has your custom table as a view and use that graph to insert the data. I am not aware of any other way. Would be the same idea if a user inside the application needed to get data in - there would need to be a graph with a view to your DAC to persist to the database.